The letter i without capitalization, is it accepted?
When writing the pronoun i in the middle of a sentence, like
I wanted to improve so i learned
or
i wanted to improve so i learned
Can this format be accepted in formal writing? or is it considered unacceptable?
The reason I am asking is because the small letter i in the middle of a sentence seems more natural, while the capital I in the middle of a sentence could be confused with the small letter l and 1, one.

@StuartF I think maybe my question is different? in the link you posted, the answer focus on the historical reason, but my question is more focused on, what if you saw the letter i not capitalized in a blog post or a news article? is it completely unacceptable?

As far as your comment about confusing I with l or 1, that's strictly dependent on the font chosen for display/print, and has no relevance to usage.

@JeffZeitlin all sans serif fonts may confuse small L with capital i,

Easy to find information on this in standard reference works. Thesaurus.com has 'While 'you' and 'me' are usually lowercase, the pronoun 'I' should always be capitalized, regardless of where it appears in a sentence.' And the question has appeared before: Is it alright to use lowercase i or should you always use I in uppercase?.

Exactly. If you don't choose a sans-serif font, you won't have confusion. Font choice is not a reason to change grammar rules.

Insights expands on the basics: 'Are There Exceptions to “I” Always Being Capitalized? –_No. When used as a first-person personal pronoun, “I” must always be capitalized. However, some companies use camel case for their product names. In these instances, you may find a [mandatory, even when sentence-initial] lowercase “i”.
iPhone, iMac, iOS, iPad'

@Jeff Zeitlin ... or, more relevantly, orthographics conventions.

@EdwinAshworth - point taken; I stand corrected.

You can get away with it only if your name is e.e. cummings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings

You can get away with it if you're writing poetry (you can get away with pretty much anything if you're writing poetry). Otherwise, no.

@Jeff Zeitlin It's Christmas. Feel free to lounge.
